# Activeadmin form use show view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

How can i implement such thing as display part of my `view` page on `edit` page

I want to show some data under my edit form.

```
  form do |f|
    f.semantic_errors(*f.object.errors.keys)
    f.inputs 'Edit SSR' do
      f.input :scope
      f.input :code
      f.input :name
    end
    f.actions

and here my view data goes
.....
end
```

I have tried to override form but no luck

How i can do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show data below the form then you can write it inside div as follows in the active_admin resource file:

```
form do |f|
 f.semantic_errors(*f.object.errors.keys)
 f.inputs 'Edit SSR' do
  f.input :scope
  f.input :code
  f.input :name
 end
 f.actions
 div id: "div_id", class: "div_class" do
   #put your data here
 end
end
```

OR you can create a partial and call it as:

```
form partial: "partial_name"
```